# How to add user in a Active directory Group using powershell

Tags: powershell

The code I have used to create user is:

```
 Import-Module ActiveDirectory

 $total = 2
 for ($userIndex=0; $userIndex -lt $total; $userIndex++) 
 { 
  $userID = “{0:0000}” -f ($userIndex + 1)
  $userName = “Super.admin$userID”

  Write-Host “Creating user” ($userIndex + 1) “of” $total “:” $userName

  New-ADUser `
   -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString “admin@123” -AsPlainText -Force) `
   -City “City” `
   -Company “Company” `
   -Country “US” `
   -Department “Department” `
   -Description (“TEST ACCOUNT ” + $userID + “: This user account does not represent a real user and is meant for test purposes only”)`
   -DisplayName “Test User ($userID)” `
   -Division “Division” `
   -EmailAddress “$userName@DESMOSEDICI.local” `
   -EmployeeNumber “$userID” `
   -EmployeeID “ISED$userID” `
   -Enabled $true `
   -Fax “703-555-$userID” `
   -GivenName “Test” `
   -HomePhone “703-556-$userID” `
   -Initials “TU$userID” `
   -MobilePhone “703-557-$userID” `
   -Name “Super.Admin ($userID)” `
   -Office “Office: $userID”`
   -OfficePhone “703-558-$userID” `
   -Organization “Organization” `
   -Path  "OU=BusinessUnit,DC=Domain,DC=com" `
   -POBox “PO Box $userID”`
   -PostalCode $userID `
   -SamAccountName $userName `
   -State “VA – Virginia” `
   -StreetAddress “$userID Any Street” `
   -Surname “User ($userID)” `
   -Title “Title” `
   -UserPrincipalName “$userName@Domain.com“
 }
```

Under my business unit group HR is created. How can I add a user in this group or create the users and assign the HR group to the users using the above script?
I tried to change the `-Path`

```
-Path "CN=HR,OU=Utility,DC=DESMOSEDICI,DC=com"
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Path is the Organizational Unit (or Container) the account will be created in. It has nothing to do with Group membership.

Use:

```
Add-ADGroupMember "CN=HR,OU=Utility,DC=DESMOSEDICI,DC=com" -Member "$userName@Domain.com"
```

Edit: This shows the command in the context of your script:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$total = 2
for ($userIndex=0; $userIndex -lt $total; $userIndex++) { 
    $userID = "{0:0000}" -f ($userIndex + 1)
    $userName = "Super.admin$userID"

    Write-Host "Creating user" ($userIndex + 1) "of" $total ":" $userName

    New-ADUser `
        -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "admin@123" -AsPlainText -Force) `
        -City "City" `
        -Company "Company" `
        -Country "US" `
        -Department "Department" `
        -Description ("TEST ACCOUNT " + $userID + ": This user account does not represent a real user and is meant for test purposes only")`
        -DisplayName "Test User ($userID)" `
        -Division "Division" `
        -EmailAddress "$userName@DESMOSEDICI.local" `
        -EmployeeNumber "$userID" `
        -EmployeeID "ISED$userID" `
        -Enabled $true `
        -Fax "703-555-$userID" `
        -GivenName "Test" `
        -HomePhone "703-556-$userID" `
        -Initials "TU$userID" `
        -MobilePhone "703-557-$userID" `
        -Name "Super.Admin ($userID)" `
        -Office "Office: $userID"`
        -OfficePhone "703-558-$userID" `
        -Organization "Organization" `
        -Path  "OU=BusinessUnit,DC=Domain,DC=com" `
        -POBox "PO Box $userID"`
        -PostalCode $userID `
        -SamAccountName $userName `
        -State "VA – Virginia" `
        -StreetAddress "$userID Any Street" `
        -Surname "User ($userID)" `
        -Title "Title" `
        -UserPrincipalName "$userName@Domain.com"

    Add-ADGroupMember "CN=HR,OU=Utility,DC=DESMOSEDICI,DC=com" -Member "$userName@Domain.com"
}
```

If you are receiving errors from New-ADUser something is wrong with your existing script, the new command is entirely separate and must fall after New-ADUser has done its job.

Comment: Not Working   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser

Comment: The error you've got it being raised by New-ADUser. The command above can only be executed after New-ADUser has finished. This must fall after your `-UserPrincipalName “$userName@Domain.com“` line as a separate command.

Comment: Added after -UserPrincipalName Still not working Add-ADGroupMember `
  -Identity "CN=SuperAdmin,OU=Utility,DC=Domain,DC=com" `
  -Member "$userName@domain.com" `

Comment: I've edited the example above, showing the command inline to clarify.

Comment: This Error occurred Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'Super.admin0002@domain.com' under: 'DC=domain,DC=COM'.
At line:44 char:3
+   Add-ADGroupMember "CN=HR,OU=Utility,DC=domain,DC=com" -Member "$ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Super.admin0002@domain.com:ADPrincipal) [Add-ADGroupMember], ADIdentity 
   NotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetADGroupMember.ValidateMembersParameter,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddAD 
   GroupMember

Comment: There are two possibilities now. Either the commands are targeting different domain controllers and replication time is playing with us, or the commands just aren't very good and they need some encouragement. If we start with the former, add a parameter to both the `New-ADUser` and `Add-ADGroupMember` commands: `-Server NameOfADomainController` to force both to act against the same Domain Controller.

Comment: Also try `Add-ADGroupMember "CN=HR,OU=Utility,DC=DESMOSEDICI,DC=com" -Member "$userName"`